# How do you create an object by a specific user in a unit test?

Tags: unit-test

I have a trigger that examines the creator of a Case object and executes code if it matches a user in a specific list. I need to unit test this code, and so I need to create a Case object, but have the CreatedBy field match the user of my choosing.

However, the CreatedById field is set automatically upon creation of the case, and is not editable.  How can I unit test this code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the System.runAs() method to execute test code as another user:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Comment: Got beaten by 4 seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ask Support to enable a feature for you that allows you to set CreatedById on inserts. Then, simply set it to the user's ID in your test method.

Comment: Support will ask you about a timeframe because they'd like to disable this access when you're done with data migration for example. And then the test will break.

Comment: @eyescream, we've had it enabled now for about 7 years. It all up to your persuasion skills

Comment: awesome, good to know next time I'll need to negotiate it ;)